# Delaying messages in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I would like to delay a message to my JMS client. 
I'm using AMQ 5.8.0. In the documentation it states to set up the config setting `schedulerSupport` to `true` (it's `false` by default)

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        persistent="false"
        dedicatedTaskRunner="false"
        schedulerSupport="true"
        brokerName="mybroker">
```

Here is my test code for producing/consuming my record

```
TextMessage sendMessage = producerSession.createTextMessage();
sendMessage.setStringProperty(Constants.PARAM_ID, newUniqueId);
long delay = 20 * 1000;
sendMessage.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, delay); //sets delay
sendMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(newUniqueId);
producer.send(sendMessage);

Message m = consumer.receive(); //get message. This should be null
if(m != null)
{
    id = m.getStringProperty(Constants.PARAM_ID); //I get the message well before 20 sec delay
}
```

I can see my record in the jetty browser under the scheduled tab. The message should be delayed by 20 seconds. However, when the `consumer.receive()` call is made, I get the record well before the 20 delay has expired..

Am I misunderstanding how this delay works? I don't want the record to be available for a period of time.

Comment: As [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive--) states, calling `javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive()` "blocks indefinitely until a message is produced or until this message consumer is closed." However, your comment says, "This should be null," which is incorrect. It will only return `null` if the `MessageConsumer` is concurrently closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` property, i.e.

```
sendMessage.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, delay);
```

and to enable persistence (by default = true, if not set):

```
<broker persistent="true">
```

Comment: Yes.. I must have chopped off some of it when I was making the post. But that is the property I'm using. It is showing in the amq jetty web browser as scheduled too.. So I don't know why I'm getting it back immediately.. It should be getting delayed

Comment: @DanielCosio persistent="false" should be changed to persistent="true" (this is the default), otherwise the messages will not be delayed.

Comment: thanks.. This is what was missing. It only works with persistent queues.

Comment: I believe in the newest broker release the in memory scheduler would be activated if persistent was set to false.